# Паттерн "Абстрактная фабрика". Конструкторы с параметрами.

Tags: абстрактная-фабрика, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Как наиболее рационально реализовать паттерн АФ, имя иерархию, где у конструктора каждого класса различаются принимаемые параметры?

Comment: А как вы пытались? Дайте код (только не много!), обсудим. "Наиболее рационально" не бывает, бывает "наиболее хорошо подходит к данной задаче".

Comment: Абстрактная фабрика подразумевает единый интерфейс для создания различных объектов из одной иерархии. Если параметры, используемые для создания этих объектов так сильно различаются, подумайте, стоит ли пользоваться фабрикой. Если же фабрика необходима, можете передавать в неё Map с параметрами, которые хотите передать в конструктор.

Comment: @fori1ton: но это же убивает весь смысл фабрики! Вам для каждого конкретного класса придётся знать, какой набор параметров нужен. Если у вас есть такая логика, вы можете просто вызвать нужный конструктор, и дело с концом, потребность в фабрике отпадает.

Comment: @VladD, полностью с Вами согласен. Отличный довод в пользу того, чтобы в данном случае отказаться от фабрики. @xopkpykc, покажите, пожалуйста, Ваш код, возможно, прочитав его мы сможем предложить более осмысленный вариант.

Comment: @fori1ton: Хороший контрдовод, 1:1 :-)

Comment: Извините, ребята, что код не добавил. Дело в том, что я его еще не дописал =). Я в паттернах слаб, почитал о фабрике в книге Фрименов. Все очень понятно и логично, но там используются конструкторы по умолчанию. 
Думал, моя ситуация очень распространенная, и получу сразу ответ, но Вы правильно мне сказали:
"Наиболее рационально" не бывает, бывает "наиболее хорошо подходит к данной задаче". Решил думать самому.
----------------------------------
Вот сейчас буду рассматривать ответ, который мне дали ниже =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

пример решения данной задачи:

```
// custom types
class CustomTypeX {}
class CustomTypeY {}

interface IConfiguration {}

class CustomConfigX implements IConfiguration{}
class CustomConfigY implements IConfiguration{}

interface IObjectFactory
{
    public CustomTypeX createObjectX(IConfiguration config); 
    public CustomTypeY createObjectY(IConfiguration config);
}

class CustomObjectFactory implements IObjectFactory {

    @ Override
    public CustomTypeX createObjectX ( IConfiguration config )
    {
        if (config instanceof CustomConfigX) {
           // create object using provided config
           return new CustomTypeX(); 
        }
        return null ;
    }

    @ Override
    public CustomTypeY createObjectY ( IConfiguration config )
    {
        if (config instanceof CustomConfigY) {
            // create object using provided config
            return new CustomTypeY(); 
         }
         return null ;
    }
}
```

для разных фабрик будут также разные имплементации конфигов

Comment: - Мне кажется, будет лучше, если будут несколько реализаций `IObjectFactory`, которые будут принимать в своих конструкторах `IConfiguration` и иметь единственный метод `createObject.`

- Так не нужно будет использовать `downcast`, возвращать неочевидный `null` в каких-то случаях и можно будет проинжектить конфиги с помощью `IoC.`

Comment: в примере, я ориентировался на то, что конфиг для разных типов создаваемых фабрикой будет разный (даже для обьектов одного типа создаваемых разными реализациями фабрики)